# Protect "Private" Objects in My R Package

Tags: r, private-members, name-binding, package-design

## Motivation

I am developing an R package (call it **`pkg`**) which collects in a running cache some objects generated by its function calls.  It is simple enough to implement the cache as a `list` object (call it `.cache`) in the **`pkg`** namespace. However, I want to prevent the user from interfering directly with the cache, which can always be exposed via the `:::` syntax: `pkg:::.cache`.

That is, I want to protect `.cache` analogously to private fields in object-oriented programming. All operations on `.cache` should be done by internal helper functions, which are called exclusively by [`@export`](https://r-pkgs.org/namespace.html#exports)ed functions with an "API flavor".

## The Problem

As such, I had the idea of defining an [`environment`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/environment.html) object (call it `.vault`) in the namespace, so I can...put my *`.cache`* in my `.vault`.

[image: 3]

My quandary is that an environment like `.vault` is one of the few things in R that work **by reference**. So I fear `pkg:::.vault` will expose `.vault` or its contents to **modification** as well as to viewing. I can alter my accessor functions like `pkg:::.get_cache()` so *they* don't enable such exposure, but all such efforts are in vain if `.vault` can be directly modified in place.

### DO NOT RUN

By way of example, consider this **dangerous** (?) code below. First I examine the internal `.S3MethodsClasses` environment from [**`dplyr`**](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org), to "identify a target":

```
dplyr:::.S3MethodsClasses
#> <environment: 0x7fab9c6c5310>

ls(dplyr:::.S3MethodsClasses)
#> [1] "grouped_df" "rowwise_df"
```

Then I examine the `rowwise_df` object and deem it a worthy "target":

```
dplyr:::.S3MethodsClasses$rowwise_df
#> Virtual Class "rowwise_df" [package "dplyr"]
#> 
#> Slots:
#> 
#> Name:                .Data               names           row.names
#> Class:                list           character data.frameRowLabels
#> 
#> Name:             .S3Class
#> Class:           character
#> 
#> Extends:
#> Class "tbl_df", directly
#> Class "tbl", by class "tbl_df", distance 2
#  ...
```

Finally, I exploit the fact that unlike most objects from the **`dplyr`** namespace...

```
library(dplyr)

mutate <- NULL

dplyr::mutate
#> function (.data, ...) 
#> {
#>     UseMethod("mutate")
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x7fab9c2f6120>
#> <environment: namespace:dplyr>
```

...an environment like `.S3MethodsClasses` **points by reference**, and so its contents can be *easily* modified in place:

```
# "Copy" the pointer to allow `<-` assignment.
same_pointer <- dplyr:::.S3MethodsClasses

same_pointer
#> <environment: 0x7fab9c6c5310>



# Modify in place.
same_pointer$rowwise_df <- NULL

dplyr:::.S3MethodsClasses$rowwise_df
#> NULL
```

**And just like that, the "vault" is robbed!**

## Suspicions

I suspect the answer might lie here, with [`lockEnvironment()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/bindenv.html) and friends, but the application is a bit beyond me.  Perhaps I could do something `.onLoad` to set up the `.vault` environment, which would then be `lock*()`ed — both the `.vault` itself and the bindings within it — but not before [making an active binding](https://rdrr.io/r/base/bindenv.html#heading-3) between `.cache` and an accessor function `.get_cache()`, which would populate within the **`pkg`** namespace.

### Note

I am already developing a feature to terminate (helper) functions like `.get_cache()` when they are called outside a fellow function from the **`pkg`** namespace. Thus, the exposure of `pkg:::.get_cache()` will not let the user operate `.get_cache()` either manually or in a custom function of their own.

## Canonicity

I would especially appreciate the advice of R developers experienced enough to provide a canonical answer (if any).

Comment: Even if could "lock" something, the user could just "unlock it". R made the decision to trust the user. You cannot hide code or values in a package that the user cannot access. If your package code can access the value, then so can the user. YOu can make the process as inconvenient as you like, but you can't make it impossible That was not a design goal of the language so you're righting an uphill battle.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, I suspected as much, given that there is an `unlock*()` for every `lock*()`...and the fact that open source language enables reverse engineering.  However, I would like to at least prevent a user's curiosity from "killing the cat", so to speak.